# Como faço um cronometro decrescente até uma data?

Tags: javascript

Bom é o seguinte eu tenho uma seguinte data com uma hora, e gostaria de saber como poderia fazer um cronometro decrescente, com dias horas minutos e segundos até chegar a essa data e essa hora.

Exemplo: A data definida no javascript é 18/08/2016 ás 20:02 e 16 segundos, ou seja o cronometro terá que mostrar decrescentemente quantos dias, horas minutos e segundos faltam até chegar a essa data com contagem decrescente em tempo real.

Como poderei fazer isso com javascript?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Isso é o mínimo pra começar, mas acho que já ajuda.

```js
//aqui vai sempre ser a hora atual
var startDate = new Date();
//como exemplo vou definir a data de fim com base na data atual
var endDate = new Date();
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate()+5);

//aqui é a diferenca entre as datas, basicamente é com isso que voce calcula o tempo restante
var dateDiff;
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
var $day = $('#dias');
var $hour = $('#horas');
var $minute = $('#minutos');
var $second = $('#segundos');
var $debug = $('#debug');
var timer;

function update(){
 dateDiff = endDate - startDate;
  dateDiff = dateDiff / 1000;
  
 seconds = Math.floor((dateDiff % 60));
  
  dateDiff = dateDiff / 60;
  minutes = Math.floor((dateDiff % 60));
 
  dateDiff = dateDiff / 60;
  hours = Math.floor((dateDiff%24));
  
 days = Math.floor(dateDiff/24);
  
  $day.text(days);
  $hour.text(hours);
  $minute.text(minutes);
  $second.text(seconds);
  
  startDate.setSeconds(startDate.getSeconds()+1);
}
update();
timer = setInterval(update, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dias"></div>
<div id="horas"></div>
<div id="minutos"></div>
<div id="segundos"></div>
<div id="debug"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar alguma blibioteca de `Countdown`, abaixo segue uma implementação usado a blibioteca desenvolvida pelo `Hugo Giraudel`

**[Countdown.js](http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/12/12/countdown/)**

```js
new Countdown({
  selector: '#countdown',
  msgAfter: "O Evento Iniciou!",
  msgPattern: "{days} dias, {hours} horas, {minutes} minutos e {seconds} segundos até a data do evento!",
  dateEnd: new Date("2016-08-18T20:02:16"),
  onEnd: function() {
    alert('O Evento Iniciou!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/HugoGiraudel/Countdown.js/master/countdown.js"></script>
<div id="countdown"></div>
```